# can i check online or offline user with twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

I am using twilio conversations for chat. Can I get information about whether the user is offline or online? I did not find any information on this in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The information about whether a user is online or offline in Twilio Conversations is known as the [reachability indicator](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/reachability). You can read about how to use it in the documentation here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/reachability

Comment: Thanks. It really helped me )